# Can I configure IIS 7+ to do a dynamic reverse proxy based on the incoming hostname?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, proxy, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I am trying to configure IIS to proxy requests based on the incoming hostname.  For example, if my proxy server is an IIS server located at www.proxy.com, a request to www.google.com.www.proxy.com would be proxied to www.google.com

I have tried to set up a reverse proxy with a URL rewrite rule to rewrite `*localhost*` to {R:1}{R:2}, but I haven't had any luck.  From what I have read, it may only be possible if I specify exactly which servers I want to interact with ahead of time, but in my case, this isn't possible (servers are on EC2 and being dynamically created and killed all the time).

Comment: Alternatively, is there a 3rd party proxy server that will do it for me?

Comment: Download Application Request Routing using the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: @TristanK I installed that and set it up as a reverse proxy with the rewrite rule I want, but it appears to require the server name, meaning that I can't decipher the new server name as part of the URL Rewrite, unless I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not that difficult to set up. Whether it's a wise thing to do though by allowing virtually any domain www.*.com.www.proxy.com to proxy to www.*.com is another thing. You should have some kind of mechanism to limit for which domains you want to proxy.

But anyway, technically you have to set up a reverse proxy with the following URL rewrite rule (with the ARR module installed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://(.*?)\.www\.proxy\.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://{C:2}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But you should really add more conditions to limit the domains for which you allow proxying.

Comment: Will this definitely work with any url?  I was under the impression that you could only rewrite to servers within your Site pool?  Also, we are accomplishing the domain limiting by setting a single domain from which the requests can come, and sitting these machines behind a load balancer.

Comment: It works fine on my test system. The only problem could be to rewrite URL's in the response with outbound rules because the URL rewrite module can not rewrite URL's in gzip compressed content.